# Is it possible to embed a mysql.dll in a Excel file by adding it to the .xlsm.zip file?

Tags: object, excel, dll, reference, vba

The client machine running the Excel workbook may or may not have the object library for MySQL installed. I do not want the client to have to install anything to run the workbook.

I know it is possible the change to file extension on the .xlsm to .zip and add files in the folder, change the extension back and it will still run as normal.

My idea is to add the .dll to the Excel file via the above process.

How do I reference a .dll from VBA?

If this is possible the .dll will be stored with the workbook itself and I will never get a "Missing Library References" error.

Comment: good question but it's not possible to attach a .dll along with the xlsm or zip. You need to have the dll as a separate file outside the zip/xlsm and add references to it through VBA